# Edit BadRequest

Tags: c#, controller, request, asp.net-core

I have an Response object that I want to return to the user if there is an exception in the controller. However when i try to send back BadRequest i cant seem to send back my Response object. So my question is how do i edit BadRequst to contain my Response object and/or how do i send back my Response object with an error status code ?

Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginViewModel model) {
    Response response = new Response(); 
    try {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded) {
                logger.LogInformation(1, "User logged in.");
                return Json("User logged in.");
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor) {
                response.id = 1 ; 
                throw new LoginException("Login requiest two factor", new InvalidOperationException());
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut) {
                response.id = 2 ; 
                logger.LogWarning(2, "User account locked out.");
                throw new LoginException("User account locked out", new InvalidOperationException());
            }
            else {
                response.id = 3 ; 
                throw new LoginException("Invalid login attempt", new InvalidOperationException());
            }
        }
        response.id = 4 ; 
        var modelErrors = ModelState.Values.ToList(); 
        throw new LoginException("Model State Error", ModelState, new InvalidOperationException());
    } catch (LoginException ex){
        return BadRequest(response); // response with status: 400 Bad Request for URL, no response object is in here. 
    }
}
```

Front-End

```
login(email:any, password:any, remember:any){
    //let body:User = {email:email, password:password}; 
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

    let body = {Email:email, Password:password,RememberMe:false }; 
    console.log(body); 
    this.http.post('/api/Account/Login', body ,{headers:headers})
    .map(response  => response.json())
    .subscribe(
         response => { 
             console.log("Success !!!:\n"+response); 
             this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        }, 
        error => {
             console.log("Error !!!:\n"+error); 
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: How is the BadRequest class defined? Also, I suggest instead of throwing exceptions and catching them immediately, you just return your BadRequest(response).

Comment: BadRequest is an helper method of Controller class and it already implies a status code: HTTP Code 400 (BadRequest) hence the name. Also you shouldn't throw exception in the controller, but return IActionResult. You're abusing Exceptions for generating error results. Exceptions are what the name says: Exceptional errors. User Lockout, or Input validation is not exceptional but expected

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you're asking?

You only want to return status code 400? Use the parameterless version of  `return BadRequest()`

Want a different status code? Use different Method. `BadRequest` is named by the HTTP Statuscode 400 (BadRequest). If you want to set the status code yourself, use `return Status(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);` or whatever.

Want to return a error message as json? Use error classes or annonymous class to do so:

```
return BadRequest(new { ErrorMessage = "Account is locked." });
```

But whatever you want to do, throwing exceptions in Controller is wrong. An controller action should **NEVER** throw an exception. Also as pointed in the comments, exceptions are to be used for **exceptional** cases. A wrong password, locked user or wrong authentication method (i.e. no two factor auth when its required) are expected errors and shouldn't be handled via excpetions.

Exceptions (when thrown only) are inherently expensive operations in a computer program. For that reason Microsoft implemented an `IdentityResult` class to return a list of expected errors, rather than throwing exceptions during the call of `signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync`

Comment: return BadRequest(new { ErrorMessage = "Account is locked." });. In the conolse i dont see The Account is locked message. But that is exactly what im trying to do. In the console it says 
Error !!!:
Response with status: 400 Bad Request for URL: http://localhost:5000/api/Account/Login"

Comment: Its not printing it in the log, its what gets returned to to the browser

Comment: So how do i get the message out of the browser?

Comment: Depends on how you consume it. If you have an javascript client, parse it and display it to the user. If you use a .NET or Java Client do the same there. That's what the rest service returns. What the consumer do with it its up to the consumer. Have you ever worked with web technologies before? Seems you have strange expectation on how it works

Comment: Yeah im using angular on the the front end. The json reponse that shows up is  Error !!!: Response with status: 400 Bad Request for URL: localhost:5000/api/Account/Login" .... There is not ErrorMessage object.

Comment: Show your angular code, I can't mind read. Sounds more like you are not registering the fail callback method when doing the request

Comment: Nvm figured it out. Also i'm going to take your advise and take out the exceptions, I just that it made the code cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning `IActionResult` why don't you return a `HttpResponseMessage` and then you can do something like: 
`return Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)`